# Handle Exception with Mockito

Tags: java, mockito

I'm using `Mockito` in my unit testing. I have a method

```
public Status getResponse(Request requset) throws DataException{
}
```

`DataException` is my own defined one which inherited from Exception class.

In my test case

```
static{
when(process.getResponse(any(Request.class))).
                thenReturn(new Status("Success"));
}
```

It gives an error, `Unhandled Exception:DataException`

Is there any way in `Mockito` to handle this issue without adding try/catch ?

Comment: and why can't you use try/catch? I think you specify exception to handle it lately.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

add this to your test method:

```
@Test(expected=DataException.class)
```

or use this :

```
then(caughtException()).isInstanceOf(DataException.class);
```

for a static-block there is no way other than try-catch.

Another way is to change `DataException` to a `RuntimeException`.

Comment: but the issue remains same in static block

Comment: This doesn't address the question.

Answer (score 8):

Don't use a `static` block.  Use a method tagged with `@Before` instead, and tack `throws Exception` onto its declaration.

Comment: This fixed my similar issue. Not sure why the answer above was marked as correct - it didn't fix it.